# 'Component.GetComponent<T>()' is a method, which is not valid in the given context [Assembly-CSharp]csharp(CS0119)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I try to get a variable from another script I get the error `'Component.GetComponent<T>()' is a method, which is not valid in the given context [Assembly-CSharp]csharp(CS0119)`

The code that's throwing the error is here
`GetComponent<EnemyAI>.Attack();`

Any help or suggestions is greatly appreciated,

Comment: `GetComponent<EnemyAI>().Attack();` should work. Note the extra `()`. You should generally get the component once and store it in a member variable if it doesn't change. `GetComponent` is not cheap so it's best to avoid calling it repeatedly to get the same object.

Comment: To be more specific, if you want to call a method then you have top use parentheses, just as you are on `Attack`. As it stands, you're trying to call `Attack` on the `GetComponent` method itself, rather than on the value returned when it's called.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you can't get the component class just by writing the type in any code, and to do this you need to have an instance of the enemyAI gameObject as a reference. In this solution The easiest way to do this is to use `GameObject.FindObjectOfType<>()` like the code below:

```
public EnemyAI enemyAI; // define a variable for enemyAI

public void Start()
{
    enemyAI = FindObjectOfType<EnemyAI>(); // it will find your enemyAI script gameObject
}
```

Once the game is begining, `EnemyAI` is stored in that variable, and you have access to the class properties. And you can easily run the methods.

```
private void OnNearEnemy()
{
    enemyAI.Attack(); // call attack function

    enemyAI.power += 10f; // add some power for example...
}
```

Now if you have another component like `Rigidbody` or `Animator` in EnemyAI, you can easily call and access it with GetComponent<>().

```
public void ForceEnemyToEscape()
{
    var enemyAgent = enemyAI.GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>(); // get nav mesh

    enemyAgent.destination = transform.position + transform.forward * 10f;
}
```

However, I suggest you learn object-oriented programming topics well. Because many calls can be made inside the enemy class. I hope it helped.

Comment: Using FindObjectOfType will return the first instance found in the scene. Pretty confident, that is not the intention when dealing with something called EnemyAI as it is likely there are many of them in the scene.

Comment: Of course, find is not a good and optimal method, and even for other reasons. The reason for this answer is not just the suggestion of using find of type, but the correct understanding of the get component logic, dear friend. @Everts

Comment: Thanks so much, this was really helpful. I still have a lot to learn about C# and programming in general, and I really appreciate you coming here to help me learn